# Show all inbox items (notifications) in app

Tags: feature-request, notifications, ios-app, global-inbox

The SE app currently only shows some inbox items:

- Answers
- Comments
- Chats

When I see those I assume I'm all caught up, but it turns out there are more on the web which aren't displayed in the app:

- Bounty expiration
- Elections
- Edits on your own posts
- Maybe others?

I was about to tag this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) but realized it's probably intentional.

I imagine the reason for not showing them is because they're not something you can act on from within the app. Bounties can't be offered or awarded<sup>1</sup> and elections can't be voted on.

But then again chats can't be replied to either. Badge descriptions can't be viewed (on the Achievements side). Selecting those launches the browser. Why then shouldn't bounties or elections launch the browser too? Hiding them just means I'll miss it if I haven't visited in browser recently.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Though accepting answers does award the bounty</sup>

Comment: You also don't get post edits and post suggested edits in the inbox.

Comment: Also missing: edit notifications when a post of yours is edited by different user. Reason most likely is lack of support on the API side though.

Comment: API is not set in iron, it can be changed and expanded as well. :)

Comment: @Shadow thanks for editing in "Edits on your own posts" by editing my own post, the notification of which I only received on the desktop, not on the app :)

Comment: lol, didn't think of the irony here! :-)

Comment: Even though the messages themselves don't show up in the app inbox, the inbox icon does get the green indicator there is something new in there. I think the fact that this will send the user to the inbox only to go "wtf I thought there was supposed to be something new in here" qualifies this as a bug. If it's intentional behaviour, I think it should also extend to the inbox icon notifications, which should not be shown for messages that are visible only on the web.

Comment: I do consider this a bug if the notification is for a ban. Users should be made aware of any sort of ban that they would have received a notification on the website for.

Comment: I came across this post while looking through requests related to the inbox... Since the app's no longer supported, I've closed this request as "no longer reproducible". (Feel free to reopen if that's incorrect, e.g. if this was already implemented in the app before it stopped being supported.)